# regexp matching bracket "(" in string

Tags: regex, escaping, scheme, racket

I am having difficulties matching brackets in strings using regex in Racket/Scheme. I thought you would have to escape the bracket since it is used for other things in regex, and I have tried:

```
(regexp-match #rx"(" "(")

(regexp-match #rx"\(" "(")

(regexp-match #rx"[\(]" "(")
```

None of these seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do have to escape the parenthesis, but regexp literals in Racket simply use ordinary string parsing, so you *also* have to escape the backslash.

```
(regexp-match #rx"\\(" "(") ; => '("(")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [**double escapes**](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28part._regexp-syntax%29) here.

```
(regexp-match #rx"\\(" "(")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme there are no `regexp-match` (that works only in `#!racket`). However you have [SRFI-115](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-115/srfi-115.html) which implement regular expressions for the standard Scheme reports. With this RE implementation the answer is this:

```
(regexp-matches? "(" "(") ; ==> #t
```

The reason you don't need to quote it is because Scheme regular expressions use list structure to express complex matches. eg:

```
(regexp-search '(w/nocase (~ ("Aab"))) "b") => #<regexp-match>
```